# npm update worked but still shows older version in mac

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I wanted to update my npm version with

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

This returns me this

```
/Users/ariful.haque/.npm-global/bin/npm -> /Users/ariful.haque/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
/Users/ariful.haque/.npm-global/bin/npx -> /Users/ariful.haque/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
```

But when I checked, its till on my old version. So, I did `which npm` and I get this result

```
/usr/local/bin/npm
```

If I try like

```
Users/ariful.haque/.npm-global/bin/npm -v
```

I receive correct version `6.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the right location `Users/ariful.haque/.npm-global/bin/npm` to yourPATH, something like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/ABSOLUTE_PATH/Users/ariful.haque/.npm-global/bin
```

Replace ABSOLUTE_PATH with thethe rest of the path. This is only work in the current terminal window, if you open other terminal window you must repeat the command. In case that you want to be permanent,, take a look of this link:

https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/add-shell-path-osx/